# BigQuery - Pivoting from a declared variable

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to pivot a table `Produce` using values from column `years`. This is accomplished below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tmp.Produce AS 
  SELECT 'Kale' as product, 51 as sales,  2020 as year UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 23, 2020 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 70, 2021 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Kale', 85, 2021 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 77, 2020 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apple', 1, 2021;

SELECT * 
FROM tmp.Produce
PIVOT(SUM(sales) yearly_sales FOR year IN (2020, 2021))
```

I would like to do the above, but instead of over `(2020,2021)`, have it over a variable `years`.  My code doing this fails.

```
DECLARE years ARRAY <INT64> DEFAULT [2020, 2021];

SELECT * 
FROM tmp.Produce
PIVOT(SUM(sales) yearly_sales FOR year IN UNNEST(years))
```

How can one pivot over an array variable?

Answer (score 0):

Since your query will be created at runtime, because the value of the parameter is not know during the starting, the query has to be started by `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and given as a string:

```sql
DECLARE years ARRAY <INT64> DEFAULT [2020, 2021];

 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
SELECT * 
FROM tmp.Produce
PIVOT(SUM(sales) yearly_sales FOR year IN ( """
 || (Select string_agg(''||x,',') from unnest(years) x)
 || "))"
```